# how to add spellckeck property to c# code

Tags: ado.net

I'm developing an application using C# 3.5 under windows form application. The problem is SpellCheck property is not available in textbox properties. I added PresentationFramework Assembly, System.Windows.Controls Namespace and System.Windows.Controls.Primitives Namespace, but still doesn't work. I'm trying to test the following example.

myTextBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;

any ideas ?...

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a [3rd party control](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) to perform spell checking. I suspect that you would want to call the spell checker's CheckSpelling() method on specific key events like spaces, commas, periods, question marks, etc.